# un active enter event when post but active button

Tags: php, button, post, enter

Hello I have a big form submit I use this `<form action = 'insert.php' method="post"  >` and Is linked to my button

```
<input type="submit"  value="Terminé" id="end" />
```

but my button is invisible until the client completed a time sheet. My bug he can press enter to finish the page but I won't. I tried :

`<form action = 'insert.php' method="post" onSubmit="return false;" >`

This make my button unusable. How do I fix it?

Comment: This part is unclear: "My bug he can press enter to finish the page but I won't."

Comment: Sorry i was trying to say when the people use my website and start to complete some input exemple after finish to type in my input 1 he can press enter to finish. But I need to fix it I don't want he press enter at all

Answer (score 1):

hope you are asking something like this

you can use a function to check whether the user has filled the values or not, then send true/false

for example in javascript

```
function test()
{
var len=document.getElementById('tt').value.length;

if(len>0)//minium he has to enter 1 character in textbox
    {
      return true;
    }else
      {
        return false;
      }
}
```

**example form**

```
<body>
<form action="" onsubmit="return test()">

  <input type="text" id="tt">

  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
  </form>
</body>
```

[**YOU can see this jsbin example**](http://jsbin.com/demipero/1/)